# How to have some pages without bottom navigation?

Tags: nativescript

I want to have bottom navigation in my app as described on [this page](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#bottomnavigation--tabs-navigation) but I also have a login page which should not have the bottom navigation tabs. So as the user enters the app, he's shown the login page and after login he should get to the first tab of the bottom navigation. The docs do not mention how this would be achieved. How can this be done?

**Attempt 1:**

app.js

```
let startPage = 'login/login-page';
if(settings.hasKey('token')){
    startPage = 'app-root';
}
application.run({ moduleName: startPage });
```

This does take me to the login page but then nothing works to get me to `app-root` or another similar page that could house a `BottomNavigation`

**Attempt 2:**

On login page, nothing happens.

app.js

```
application.run({ moduleName: 'app-root' });
```

app-root.xml

```
<Frame defaultPage="login/login-page"></Frame>
```

login/login-page.js

```
//send email and password. check if its correct. send user forward on authentication
page.frame.navigate({
    moduleName: 'router/router-page',
    clearHistory: true
});
```

router/router-page.xml

```
<BottomNavigation id="bottomNav" automationText="tabNavigation" selectedIndex="0">
    <TabStrip>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Image src="font://&#xe41d;" class="mdi"></Image>
            <Label text="Products"></Label>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Image src="font://&#xe413;" class="mdi"></Image>
            <Label text="Gallery"></Label>
        </TabStripItem>
    </TabStrip>
    <TabContentItem>
        <Frame id="main" defaultPage="categories/categories-page"></Frame>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <Frame id="gallery" defaultPage="gallery/gallery-page"></Frame>
    </TabContentItem>
</BottomNavigation>
//note there's no router-page.js
//is it necessary?
```

Answer (score 0):

This exact scenario can be found in this post:

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation

The repo (https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng) is using `TabView` but you can quickly change that to use the newer `BottomNavigation` instead.

Comment: Hi Tim, I don't know Angular and I tried to follow the flow diagrams in the link you gave but its not working out for me so far. Can you suggest something? I can't navigate to the `app-root` after going into login. Also, check the added code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I finally did it

app.js

```
application.run({ moduleName: 'app-root' });
```

app-root.xml

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true" loaded="onLoaded" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <Frame id="rootframe" defaultPage="{{ defaultPage }}"></Frame>
</Page>
```

app-root.js

```
const Observable = require("@nativescript/core/data/observable").fromObject;
const settings = require("@nativescript/core/application-settings");

exports.onLoaded = function(args){
    const page = args.object;

    page.bindingContext = Observable({
        defaultPage: (settings.hasKey('token')) ? 'router/router-page' : 'login/login-page'
    })
}
```

router/router-page.xml

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true" loaded="onLoaded" class="page" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <BottomNavigation id="bottomNav" automationText="tabNavigation" selectedIndex="0" selectedIndexChanged="onSelectedIndexChanged">
        <TabStrip>
            <TabStripItem>
                <Image src="font://&#xe41d;" class="mdi"></Image>
                <Label text="Products"></Label>
            </TabStripItem>
            <TabStripItem>
                <Image src="font://&#xe413;" class="mdi"></Image>
                <Label text="Gallery"></Label>
            </TabStripItem>
        </TabStrip>
        <TabContentItem>
            <Frame id="main" defaultPage="categories/categories-page"></Frame>
        </TabContentItem>
        <TabContentItem>
            <Frame id="gallery" defaultPage="gallery/gallery-page"></Frame>
        </TabContentItem>
    </BottomNavigation>
</Page>
```